# Getting error while loading rdf file SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"

Tags: java, rdf, slf4j, jena, ontology

```
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;

public class ontology {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    FileManager.get().addLocatorClassLoader(ontology.class.getClassLoader());
    Model model = FileManager.get().loadModel("C:/Users/avg/workspace/Jena/src/ontology.rdf");
    model.write(System.out,"RDF/JSON");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the library sfl4j to your classpath

Comment: I added all the jars in my eclipse library.

Comment: Alright, can you add in you post the stacktrace showing the error ?

Comment: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/util/XMLChar
 at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.Util.notNameChar(Util.java:121)
 at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.Util.splitNamespace(Util.java:79)
 at com.hp.hpl.jena.graph.Node_URI.getLocalName(Node_URI.java:64)
 at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ResourceImpl.getLocalName(ResourceImpl.java:127)

Comment: slf4j is not the root cause here - "NoClassDefFoundError" means you have a jar configuration problem. Use all the jars in the Jena distribution you are using (you haven't said which version) or better still use maven to manage your project.

Comment: Thank you sir....Problem solved i tried with another with versions of jar, eclipse even java also and it worked with java j and eclipse indigo finally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a provider of slf4j to your path and configure it.  `LogCtl.setLog4j` or `LogCtl.setCmdLogging` are quick ways to do this in Jena.

Comment: LogCtl.setLog4j what is this? and how to configure it? I am not getting what you are saying? will you elaborate please?

Comment: LogCtl is an internal part of Jena that sorts out logging in some default way. You must have *all* the jars in the Jena lib directory on your classpath.

Comment: Sir i have all the jars in my class path Please help me how to sort out from it??.